# jquery gallery failing to work

Tags: jquery

I am Getting error on my jquery gallery. the error occurs near when I am ending script with  near the bottom, I added java for loop as pictures are named from 0-170:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- load Galleria -->
<script src="galleria-1.2.7.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Galleria Classic Theme</h1>
        <p>Demonstrating a basic gallery example.</p>

        <!-- Adding gallery images. We use resized thumbnails here for better performance, but it’s not necessary -->

<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready 
      var galleria = $('#galleria') 
      for(var i=0;i<170;i++){     
      var imgName = "images/"+i+".JPG"     
      galleria.append('<a href="'+imgName+'"><img src="'+imgName+'"></a>')
      {


    // Load the classic theme
    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria.classic.min.js');

    // Initialize Galleria
    Galleria.run('#galleria');

       </script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: really terrible code format, could you please make them looks better?

Comment: What is the error?  I imagine it's a parser error, since there's no way this JavaScript will parse successfully.  You're missing a lot of structural elements, such as brackets and parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading jQuery version 1 from googleapis.com. The gallery plugin likely requires a more recent version of jQuery.

Current version is 1.7.2:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Also, you are missing lots of parentheses and brackets. I recommend semi-colons at the end of your lines, too.

The jQuery ready function takes a function as its argument, so you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    <your code here>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

think it could be that you loaded jquery.js three times